# Rewriting from https to http with htaccess how to remove port number?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

Im having this htaccess code

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [AND] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /products-page/bathroom-amenities/nourish-a-spa-line/
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/bathroom-amenities/286-nourish.html
</IfModule>
```

what this does is to redirect the user from:

- https://www.mydomain.com/products-page/bathroom-amenities/nourish-a-spa-line/

to:

- http://www.mydomain.com:443/bathroom-amenities/286-nourish.html

This Code is redirecting from a https URL to a http URL, but for this to work I need to remove the port from the result URL.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can't you just hardcode the domain name?

Answer (score 0):

User SERVER_NAME instead of HTTP_HOST

Be careful with the use of UseCanonicalName setting, most likely you want to have it set to Off